Should GraphQL ID be used for input fields?
Does it have any affect? My understanding is that ID is primarily used for caching, which implies it should only be used for type objects and not input.
Example where we fetch a thing by id:
type Thing {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

// thing(id: ID!): Thing
thing(id: String!): Thing


There's nothing wrong with having an ID in an input type, for example when looking up a record by id or mutating a an existing record based on its id.
What you probably want to avoid is inserting a new record with an id provided by the client - best to let the back end create ids.
